# Spring + firebird

Tags: spring, firebird, jaybird

did anyone succeed with connecting spring to a .gdb database or .fdb database? 
I need little help to execute some query and display it on the screen.
There is almost no information on the internet about connecting spring to firebird...

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959433/spring-jdbc-and-firebird-database

Comment: Connecting with spring to Firebird using Jaybird would be the same as any other JDBC driver. Could you be more specific as to what problems you have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JDBC and Firebird Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959433/spring-jdbc-and-firebird-database)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using spring boot with maven update your application.properties with following

```
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:\\firebird\\firebird.GDB
spring.datasource.driverClassName:org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
spring.datasource.username:SYSDBA
spring.datasource.password:masterkey
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:update
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

and remember to set your gdb location, username, password accordingly.

And add following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: work great on Windows, but on Mac there is a problem with javax...
anyway thanks! do you have maybe some example implementation?

Comment: @PawełMeller Could you be more specific about _"there is a problem with javax..."_

Answer (score 1):

I use java8, gradle 6.6.1, SpringBoot 2.2.6 and jaybird-jdk16:2.2.13

In aplication properties:
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:firebirdsql:XXX.XXX.X.XXX:/databases/firebird/name_file.fdb
spring.datasource.password = XXXX
spring.datasource.username = XXXX

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false